# How to create TPS dashboard in grafana with elasticsearch as the source

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter, grafana, dashboard

[In graphana, i am not sure how to add queries for obtaining the TPS graph, and this is first time am using grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlSkM.png)[This the Tps graph in jmeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oXDPK.png)[image: datafield from elasticsearch listener from jmeter]

In the image i get few fields, using that i need to create a dashboard for TPS (transaaction per second). i am not able to create a dashboard for TPS which would be countofresponsecode(for no of transaction)/time interval(duration selected in the grafana)

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing can you please elaborate?

Comment: it would be great if you can give me some idea or sample json where i can retrive the TPS for the jmeter test executions. As i am new to grafana, i am not sure abt how to write a query for the same
my elk stack is jmeter-->elastic search--> kibana-->grafana, now my datasource to my grafana is elasticsearch, i have confgured it. calcuating or query to retrive the TPS is where i am stuck